# Numeric center in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, mathematics

I got a proposed exercise from a Java2 book. This one wants me to find out the numeric centers.

A numeric center splits two list of numbers that make the same result when you add the numbers in each list. For example, 6 is the first numeric center because 1+2+3+4+5=15 and 7+8=15 too. The second numeric center is 35 because 1+2+3..+34=595 and 36+37+38+39=595 too.

```
 //I'll call the Numeric Center cn from here.
public class cnumerico {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int n, index, fsum, ssum;
        n=204; //The higher number we would get.
        index=1; //No explanation need I guess. 
        fsum=0; //Stands for first sum.
        ssum=1; //Stands for second sum.
        do{
            for (int i=1;i<index;i++){
                fsum=fsum+i; //We make the first sum from 1 until it reaches the index.
                }
            for (int j=index+1;j<index*2;j++){
                if (ssum==fsum){
                    System.out.println(index+" es un centro numerico.");
                    break;
                    //In this if I check if the numbers are equal, if it is we found our cn so I stop the loop.
                    }else{
                        ssum=ssum+j;
                        }
                //If we still didn't find our cn this else does the sum from index(+1 because the cn musn't be in the sum).
                }
            index++;
            fsum=0;ssum=0; //Resetting the sums to start again.
        }while (index<n+1);
    }
}
```

It works, but I have a feeling that I could do it much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About the code itself(not the algorithm used):

1. Class name usually starts with a capital letter in Java.
2. Variables' names: it is better to use more meaningful names. For example, a name `firstSum` is much clearer then `fsum`.
3. Variable declaration and initialization: it is a good practice to make a scope of each variable as narrow as possible. It means that `fsum` and `ssum` should be declared inside the loop's body.
4. If the number of iterations of a loop is known, it makes more sense to use `for` loop then `do ... while`. Conversely, when the number of iterations is not known, using `while` is better than using `for` and `break`.
5. Surrounding operators by whitespaces makes the code more readable:

   ```
   for (int j = index + 1; j < index * 2; j++)
   ```

   looks better than

   ```
   for (int j=index+1;j<index*2;j++){
   ```
6. You should use proper and consistent indentation(closing bracket indented by 4 spaces looks strange).
7. I would declare a magic number(204) as a `final static` field of this class, not as a local variable(and a name `n` is not good for it because it is not meaningful).

So an improved version of your code can look like this:

```
public class NumericalCenter {

    private final static int MAX_CANDIDATE = 204;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int candidate = 1; candidate <= MAX_CANDIDATE; candidate++) {
            int firstSum = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < candidate; i++)
                firstSum += i;
            int secondSum = 0;
            int i = candidate + 1;
            while (secondSum < firstSum) {
                secondSum += i;
                i++;
            }
            if (firstSum == secondSum)
                System.out.println(candidate + " is a numerical center");
        }
    }
}
```

Now about the algorithm itself: let's assume that a candidate number is fixed(let's call it `x`). Then we get an equation:
$${n(n+1) \over 2} - {x(x+1) \over 2} = {x(x-1) \over 2}$$

It is a quadratic equation(with respect to `n`), so it can be solved in `O(1)`(which gives `O(MAX_CANDIDATE)` time complexity in total). However, it is not necessary for `MAX_CANDIDATE = 204`.